# Query Laravel Eloquent many to many where all id's are equal

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I making a project based on Laravel and have the tables: `companies`, `attributes`, and `attribute_company` related as Many To Many relation when `attribute_company` use as a pivot table to connect `companies` and `attributes` tables.

I get an array of `attribute_id`'s from the client and I need to get results of the companies that has the whole attributes exactly.

The only solution I found is to query `whereHas` combined with `whereIn` inside like this:

```
Company::whereHas('attributes', function (Builder $query) use ($atts_ids) {
     $query->whereIn('attribute_id', $atts_ids);
})->get();
```

This query will return `companies` if at least one `attribute_id` found (which is not what I am looking for).

It would be great if anybody can make it clearer for me.

Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: try with adding foreach loop in whereHas function.

Comment: @JinalSomaiya I have tried it already mate, unfortunately it's not working :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
$company = new Company();
$company = $company->newQuery();

foreach($atts_ids as $att_id)
{
    $company = $company->whereHas('attributes', function (Builder $query) use ($att_id) {
        $query->where('attribute_id', $att_id);
    });
}

$company = $company->get();
```